# how to get table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am new at php, how to connect and get table value when i open http://localhost/x/x.php?push=1
i am trying to echoing the result but when i try it, it shows nothing

right now i am doing like this and it's not working

```php
<?php
    //this block is to post message to GCM on-click
    $pushStatus = "";   
    if(!empty($_GET["push"])) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bimbinganpa");
        $list_dosen = array();
        $test ="test";
        $list_dosen = $mysqli->query("SELECT no FROM user_id WHERE tipe_user = mahasiswa");
        echo $list_dosen;

        $lines=array();
        $fp=fopen('GCMRegId.txt', 'r');
        while (!feof($fp)){
            $line=fgets($fp);
            //process line however you like
            $line=trim($line);
            //add to array
            $lines[]=$line;
        }

        $gcmRegID  = file_get_contents("GCMRegId.txt");
        $pushMessage = $_POST["message"];   
        if (isset($gcmRegID) && isset($pushMessage)) {      
            $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
            $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($lines, $pushMessage);
        }       
    }
?>
```

Comment: check your web server error log.

Comment: First off, strings in SQL need to be quoted: `column = 'value'`. Also, on a successful SELECT query using `$mysqli->query()`, it will return a mysqli result objects which you can't echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String needs a quotation in query...

can you try like following

```
SELECT no FROM user_id WHERE tipe_user = 'mahasiswa'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string is not having quotation. If you are trying to compare string in QUERY then you have to add quotation

Please below query for reference

```
SELECT no FROM user_id WHERE tipe_user = 'mahasiswa'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are echoing the result that database return, Indeed it never works. So you have to write loop to loop through and fetch data in every row like below and add single quote in query to make it string to compare.

```
    $list_dosen = $mysqli->query("SELECT no FROM user_id WHERE tipe_user = 'mahasiswa'");
    if ($list_dosen->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while($row = $list_dosen->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["columnName"];
       }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
```

First check that result have some rows by `num_rows` and then fetch rows by method `fetch_assoc()`. In while loop you can get value of every row's column

Comment: no, a string to compare

Comment: thanks so much, your echo is working, but the string must need quotation in query like antony said so i need to accept antony answer

Comment: yes I know but I cleared your confusion about result and rows.